# Is it possible for me to extract just the title using regex?

Tags: python, html

I have a problem with extracting title because I manage to extract 
 it but 
it's not specific to "title" only and it extracts other stuff as 
  well
 How will I be able to make a regex for that?

I tried using (?!>)([^><]+?)(?= tags too

```
    <rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 

    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:nyt="http://www.nytimes.com/namespaces/rss/2.0" version="2.0">
    <script/>
    <channel>
    <title>NYT > Top Stories</title>
    <link>https://www.nytimes.com?emc=rss&partner=rss</link>
    <atom:link 
  href="https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml" 
     rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
    <description/>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019 The New York Times Company</copyright>
    <lastBuildDate>Thu, 17 Oct 2019 22:53:19 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <image>
    <title>NYT > Top Stories</title>
    <url>
    https://static01.nyt.com/images/misc/NYT_logo_rss_250x40.png
    </url>
    <link>https://www.nytimes.com?emc=rss&partner=rss</link>
    </image>
    <item>
    <title>
    Mulvaney Says Trump Held Back Ukraine Aid Pending Investigation of 
     Democrats
    </title>
    <link>
    https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/17/us/politics/mick-mulvaney-trump- 
     ukraine.html?emc=rss&partner=rss
    </link>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">
    https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/17/us/politics/mick-mulvaney-trump- 
     ukraine.html
    </guid>
    <atom:link href="https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/17/us/politics/mick- 
     mulvaney-trump-ukraine.html?emc=rss&partner=rss" rel="standout"/>
    <description>
    Undercutting President Trump’s denial of a quid pro quo, the acting 
    White House chief of staff told reporters that military aid was held 
      back in part to prod Ukraine to investigate Democrats.
    </description>
    <dc:creator>Michael D. Shear</dc:creator>

    I
```

am extracting everything which ends with title and how to make it 
        `specific that I want to extract the below mentioned part only and 
         not the other content`

```
     <item>
    <title>
    Mulvaney Says Trump Held Back Ukraine Aid Pending Investigation of 
     Democrats
    </title>
```

It is possible for me to grab just that title, it'd be a huge help if someone can help me with this, I have been struggling for days.

Comment: Use an xml parser such as the [ones included](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) in the standard library, or [lxml](https://lxml.de/index.html), or [feedparser](https://pypi.org/project/feedparser/) specifically for rss.

Comment: there are multiple titles between <title> and </title>, is there anything else that can help narrow it down to the exact one you want?

Comment: <item>\n<title>\n[A-Za-z].*\n</title> so I used this and it selects all but I just want the content inside the two title tags